# How to create own jQuery-like function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i create a function which looks like the jquery callback $

Say i want to call a element with id= "mydiv".

i want to be able to call it like

```
var div = $("mydiv").value;
```

i think the function should look like

```
function $(element)
{
  return  document.getElementById(element);
}
```

Is that the right way to do it, or do you prefer another way to solve it?

Comment: So, Bob comes along to look at some code that has landed in his lap and discovers that it is using a `$` function. "%$@£%!", he sighs, "Is this jQuery? No. Maybe prototype.js is in there somewhere? Oh, it's a custom routine. Why can't people give their variables useful names?"

Comment: Name the function something like getElem("id") if you want to shorten document.getElementById("id"). I wrote some like that before and added a optional context parameter for iframes etc. getElem("id", context). This was before I discovered jQuery. Using $ would just be confusing to anyone else reading your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it one of three ways:

**local scope**:

```
function $(element)
{
  return  document.getElementById(element);
}
```

or

```
var $ = function(element)
{
  return  document.getElementById(element);
}
```

or if you need it to be defined in **global scope**:

```
window.$ = function(element)
{
  return  document.getElementById(element);
}
```

**If you have included `jQuery`, defining `$` in the global scope will override it. Use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to avoid this.**

Answer (score -1):

jQuery actually returns a custom object so you can call $('#id').someJqueryFunction(). If you simply want a shortcut for document.getElementById,

```
var $ = document.getElementById;
```

should suffice.

Comment: Will fail in many browsers. Remember that when you extract a method from an object and then call it from the now-unbound reference, `this` will not be set. So calling `$` will not pass the right `document` object to the `getElementById` function.